# how to remove overflow:hidden on specific object

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jcarousel

I am a creating a drag and drop web application that uses [this link](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement) and I have many images that can drag on the stage.

Here's my layout:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|            STAGE DROP AREA                         |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------------+
|  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  |
|< |IMG A |  |IMG B |  |IMG C |  |IMG D |  |IMG E | >|
|  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

The code for drag and drop is working but my problem now is the image A..N is not draggable when I add jCarousel class (css). I use JCarousel to navigate images (if I have more than 5 images) left to right.

Everytime I drag the image, the image is hiding/disappear. I think the problem is `overflow:hidden` in the `.jcarousel` class.

Is it possible to disregard parent layout `.jcarousel` or the `overflow:hidden` in every images?

.aspx

```
<div class="jcarousel">  
        <ul>
            <li> <asp:Image ID="ImageA" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/Image.png" CssClass="Drag"/></li>
            <li> <asp:Image ID="ImageB" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/Image.png" CssClass="Drag"/></li>
            <li> <asp:Image ID="ImageC" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/Image.png" CssClass="Drag"/></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS file

```
 .jcarousel {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

.jcarousel ul {
width: 20000em;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.jcarousel li {
float: left;
}
```

Comment: kudos on the ASCII art image, but its really hard to debug ASCII art.  Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry I can't our network blocks fiddle.

Comment: To disregard overflow: hidden, just override it with a more specific selector... but that won't fix your problem. div.jcarousel {overflow: visible;} The problem is probably due to the javascript added styles... added by the carousel.

Comment: I think i have a solution, please post your jquery .draggable call code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you post your `.draggable` code, I can post a more specific answer, but maybe this will help.  Below is a sample `.draggable` call.  Don't worry if yours doesn't look *exactly* just like this, the only thing you should add is the `appendTo: "body"` line

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
        revert : true,
        helper: "clone",
        opacity: 0.7, 
        zIndex: 999,
        appendTo: "body",
        drag : function() {
        }
    });
```

again.. only add the `appendTo: "body"` line to your code.  This will make your draggable items be "relative" to the body, and not
the carousel anymore, once they are dragged.